# Intuition behind independent events in the pebble world

Tags: probability, independence

In the Pebble World, the definition says that probability behaves like mass: the mass of an empty pile of pebbles is $0$, the total mass of all the pebbles is $1$, and if we have non-overlapping piles of pebbles, we can get their combined mass by adding the masses of the individual piles. The pebbles can be of differing masses and we can also have a countably infinite number of pebbles as long as their total mass is $1$.

[image]

In the above image, suppose each pebble weighs $\frac{1}{9}$ (for brevity). The pebbles inside the red box denote event $A$ and the pebbles inside the green box denote the event $B$. Note that the two boxes are intersecting.

If I am to go by the formula, then $P(A \cap B) = \frac{2}{9} = \frac{3}{9} \cdot \frac{6}{9} = P(A) \cdot P(B)$. This means $A$ and $B$ are independent events. **Independent events are such that the occurrence of one event says nothing about the occurrence of the other event. How is that exactly happening in this pebble world?** I don't understand the independence of events intuitively.

Comment: I like to think of it like this: to say that events $A$ and $B$ are independent means that $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$. If we restrict our attention to pebbles in the red box, then our probability of selecting a pebble in the green box is $2/3$, the same as if we had not restricted attention to the red box. But that statement $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$ doesn't make sense when $P(B) = 0$, so we instead use the definition that $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addendum added to respond to comment question.

---

My take on the posted question is geometric.  The red box of pebbles is row specific (1st row only) but column neutral.  This means that the chance that a pebble is in the red box is independent of which column the pebble is in.

The blue box is the opposite: column specific (2nd and 3rd columns only), but row neutral.  This means that the chance that a pebble is in the blue box is independent of which row the pebble is in.

So, when examining whether a pebble is in the blue box, the added the information that the pebble is in the red box **can not** affect the chance that the pebble is in the blue box.

This is because the information that the pebble is in the red box is row specific and column neutral.  Since the blue box is row neutral, specifying that the pebble is in a particular row can not possibly affect the probability of whether the pebble is in the blue box.

---

**Addendum**
Response to the comment question of dictatemetokcus.

Throughout this addendum, it is assumed that
$p(A) \neq 0 \neq p(B).$

Using [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem), you have that **regardless** of whether events $A,B$ are independent:

$$p(A|B) ~p(B) = p(A \cap B) = p(B|A) ~p(A). \tag1$$

Using (1) above, and also using [the definition of independent events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Definition), you have that:

Events $A,B$ are independent 
$\iff~ p(A) ~p(B) = p(A \cap B)$ 
$\iff~ p(A|B) = p(A)$ 
$\iff~ p(B|A) = p(B)$.

Let $C$ denote the event that a pebble is in the  blue box. 
Let $D$ denote the event that a pebble is in the  red box.

Then, based on the above analysis, with $p(C) \neq 0 \neq p(D)$, 
you have that events $C,D$ are independent 
$\iff ~p(C|D) = p(C)$.

The portion of my answer before the Addendum demonstrates that $p(C|D) = p(C).$

Comment: yes this is a good explanation.  Choosing a pebble randomly is equivalent to randomly, independently choosing a row and a column.  The example actually explains independence quite well.

Comment: Okay, how does this explain that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$ when two events are independent?

Comment: @dictatemetokcus See the just added Addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but could you please explain that to me with a geometric proof? That'd be very helpful.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus I'm unsure what you mean by *geometric proof*.  Let $C,D$ be as I defined them in my addendum.  If you look at the original diagram that you posted, you will see that: $$p(C) = \frac{6}{9}, ~~p(D) = \frac{3}{9}, ~~\text{and}~~ p(C \cap D) = \frac{2}{9}.$$ Therefore $$p(C) \times p(D) = p(C \cap D).$$  If this isn't the type of response that you are looking for, please be more explicit in what you intend by the phrase *geometric proof*.

Comment: Well like, I am looking for a more intuitive proof. The pebble diagram does confirm that $P(CD) = P(C)P(D)$ but this does not feel very intuitive. When you write $P(C|D) = P(C)$, it corresponds to *the occurrence of $C$ remains unchanged even though $D$ occurs*. But the multiplication does not mean anything like that.. just from the equation.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus Just to be clear, are you comfortable accepting the first part of my answer as a geometric/intuitive explanation for why $p(C|D) = p(C)$?  If so, then if I understand you, you are instead looking for a geometric/intuitive explanation *instead* of why $p(C \cap D) = p(C) \times p(D).$  For what it's worth, given Bayes Theorem and the consequential equivalent definitions of independence of events, I personally have always focused on intuitively demonstrating independence merely by intuiting that $p(C|D) = p(C).$  I've never heard nor seen of any other purely intuitive approach.

Comment: That makes sense. In fact, on a different question, someone pointed out that the product version of independence follows from $P(C|D) = P(C)$. It seems natural, so that might actually be the case.